# Collections of Lines Passing Through Few Points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Consider a collection $L$ of non-vertical lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We will think of each $\ell\in L$ as a function $\ell(x)=ax+b$. For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $S_x=\{\ell(x):\ell\in L\}$, the set of all $y$-coordinates of the lines in $L$ at input $x$. Let $n>0,w>1$ be integers, with $w\gg n$. We will say that $L$ is $(n,w)$-good if $|S_0|,|S_1|,|S_w|,|S_{w+1}|\leq n$.

**Conjecture:** There exists a constant $C$ such that, for any $n>1$ and for sufficiently large $w$, if $L$ is $(n,w)$-good, then $|L|\leq Cn$.

**Questions:** Prove or disprove conjecture. If the conjecture is true, how small can $w$ be to make it true?

**Bonus:** I'm actually mostly interested in the finite field case, replacing $\mathbb{R}$ with a finite field of characteristic $\gg w$. If the conjecture is true over finite fields, how small can the characteristic be?

### What I Know:

$w$ needs to be somewhat big. For example, suppose $w=2$, meaning we are looking at the $y$-coordinates at the points $0,1,2,3$. In this case, consider the set $L$ of all lines whose $y$ coordinates at each of $x=0,1,2,3$ are integers in $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$. $L$ is clearly $(n,2)$-good. On the other hand, $L$ contains any line $\ell(x)=ax+b$ for integer $a,b$ such that $0\leq a < n$ and $0\leq a+3b< n$. We can lower bound the size of $L$ by considering $0\leq b<n/6$. There are $n/6$ such $b$, and for each $b$, there are at least $n/2$ possible choices of $a$, giving a total of at least $n^2/12$ lines. For large $n$, $n^2/12$ will dominate any $Cn$.

If you try to extend to arbitrary $w$, but keeping the sets $S_0=S_1=S_w=S_{w+1}=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, you end up with fewer lines as $w$ increases, to the point where $|L|=n$ for $w>n$.

For general $w$, you can easily find an $L$ with $|L|\approx (4/3)n$. For $n=3$, pick an arbitrary line $\ell_0$. Then pick an arbitrary point $P$ with $x$-coordinate $0$. Let $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ be lines through $P$ that intersect $\ell_0$ at $1,w,w+1$, respectively. Let $L=\{\ell_0,\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3\}$. For general $n$, repeat $n/3$ times with new $\ell_0,P$. My guess is with some extra work, you can probably get $|L|$ close to $2n$.

For the finite field case, clearly if the field only contains $n$ elements, or even if it contains a sub-field of $n$ elements, then $L$ can just be all the lines in in the field or subfield, achieving $|L|=n^2$. However, in the large characteristic case, the largest $L$ I know are the ones above.